# Problems launching a process with Process.Start() - how do I construct the argument list?

Tags: c#, string

I've got this:

```
string cmd = " -i """ + finPath + """ -ar 44100 -ab 160k """ + foutPath + """";
```

and I need to pass it to command prompt from C# using `Systems.Diagnostics.Process`.

No combination seems to work. Program works just fine if I run it in command prompt.
Also runs just fine if I use the same string in VB.Net

`finPath` has spaces as does `foutPath` and it's making the program not run.

I need to have `finPath` expressed as `finPath`. Same with `foutPath`.

---

More of the code (used the line suggested here, no luck):

```
string inputPath = RootPath + "videoinput\\";  

string ffmpegpath = RootPath + "ffmpeg.exe"; //ffmpeg path

string outputPath = RootPath +"videooutput\\"; 

//define new extension

string fileext = ".flv";

string newfilename = namenoextension + fileext;

string namenoextension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(savedfile);

string fileoutPath = outputPath + newfilename;

string fileinPath = "/videoinput/" + savedfile;

string cmd = " -i \"" + fileinPath + "\" -ar 44100 -ab 160k \"" + fileoutPath + "\"";


//Begin encoding process

Process proc = new Process();

proc.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpegpath;

proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;

proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

proc.Start();
```

Comment: Please post all the code that launches the process.  It is hard to decipher what the issue is just from the command line args

Comment: this is needed to run:

ffmpeg.exe -i "C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\project\videoinput\eaf2cc1d-6MTNTUGOFWAR.wmv" -ar 44100 -ab -160k "videooutput\eaf2cc1d-6MTNTUGOFWAR.flv"

Comment: http://dotnetwizarrd.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-generate-video-thumbnails-using.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
string arguments = string.Format("-i \"{0}\" -ar 44100 -ab 160k \"{1}\"", finPath, foutPath);
Process.Start(thePathToExecutable, arguments);
```

Make sure to specify the executable's path separate from the command line arguments.

---

Edit in response to comments and question edit:

I just ran this in a console, using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string RootPath = "C:\\";
        string savedFile = "test.avi";

        string inputPath = Path.Combine(RootPath, "videoinput");
        string ffmpegpath = Path.Combine(RootPath, "ffmpeg.exe"); //ffmpeg path
        string outputPath = Path.Combine(RootPath, "videooutput");

        //define new extension
        string fileext = ".flv";
        string namenoextension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(savedFile);
        string newfilename = namenoextension + fileext;

        string fileoutPath = Path.Combine(outputPath, newfilename);
        string fileinPath = Path.Combine(inputPath, savedFile);

        string arguments = string.Format("-i \"{0}\" -ar 44100 -ab 160k \"{1}\"", fileinPath, fileoutPath);

        Console.WriteLine(ffmpegpath);
        Console.WriteLine(arguments);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This writes out:

```
C:\ffmpeg.exe
-i "C:\videoinput\test.avi" -ar 44100 -ab 160k "C:\videooutput\test.flv"
```

As I said - if you do it this way, it should work.  That being said, I'd recommend reading up on the [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class, and use Path.Combine(), Path.GetFullPath(), etc, to fix your input files.  This may help you correct part of your issue, as well.

Comment: comes out as:

"-i \"videoinput/file.wmv\" -ar 44100 -ab 160k \"C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\projectname\\videooutput/eaf2cc1d-6mtnR.flv\"" 

the \ after -i and the \ after 160k is still a problem when you run in command prompt, although there is now a quotation mark around the filenames.

Comment: @Haste: I just edited to show you how to make this work.  I put an entire program in the source - and tested it.  This definitely works.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Reed. 

Unfortunately my code still shows up in the debugger as -i \ "videoinput/file.wmv" -ar 44100 -ab 160k \ "C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\projectname\videooutput/eaf2cc1d-6mtnR.flv" 

(notice the back slash after -i and 160k) and still won't run. 

I had this run just fine in Vb.net using: cmd = " -i """ & filePath & """ -ar 44100 -ab 160k """ & encodefileoutPath & """" 

Don't know while c# is such a pain.

Comment: @Haste: Try using the code I put in my edit, instead of trying to use + to concatenate your strings.  I tested it, and it works, with no extra stuff (as you can see in my reply).  The switch to using String.Format is much easier to read, and less problematic.

Comment: Works. Thank you so very much.
Just had to make a few changes for design and database reasons.

Thanks.

Comment: Figured I should add that I didn't think it was working because the debugger was still showing the backslashes, but then I let it run through the breakpoints and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for [CommandLineToArgvW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391(VS.85).aspx) describes how the arguments are parsed. Interpreting this:

1. Any argument that contains whitespace should be surrounded in
   outer quotes.
2. Any inner quotes in the argument should be preceded by
   backslashes.
3. Backslashes (or sequences of backslashes) that precede
   a quote should be doubled up.

The following class can be used to achieve these results:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides helper functionality for working with Windows process command-lines.
/// </summary>
public static class WindowsCommandLineHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Performs escaping and quoting of arguments where necessary to
    /// build up a command-line suitable for use with the
    /// <see cref="System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string,string)" /> method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="arguments">The arguments to be included on the command-line.</param>
    /// <returns>The resulting command-line.</returns>
    public static string FormatCommandLine(params string[] arguments)
    {
        return string.Join(" ", arguments.Select(GetQuotedArgument));
    }

    private static string GetQuotedArgument(string argument)
    {
        // The argument is processed in reverse character order.
        // Any quotes (except the outer quotes) are escaped with backslash.
        // Any sequences of backslashes preceding a quote (including outer quotes) are doubled in length.
        var resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        var outerQuotesRequired = HasWhitespace(argument);

        var precedingQuote = false;
        if (outerQuotesRequired)
        {
            resultBuilder.Append('"');
            precedingQuote = true;
        }

        for (var index = argument.Length - 1; index >= 0; index--)
        {
            var @char = argument[index];
            resultBuilder.Append(@char);

            if (@char == '"')
            {
                precedingQuote = true;
                resultBuilder.Append('\\');
            }
            else if (@char == '\\' && precedingQuote)
            {
                resultBuilder.Append('\\');
            }
            else
            {
                precedingQuote = false;
            }
        }

        if (outerQuotesRequired)
        {
            resultBuilder.Append('"');
        }

        return Reverse(resultBuilder.ToString());
    }

    private static bool HasWhitespace(string text)
    {
        return text.Any(char.IsWhiteSpace);
    }

    private static string Reverse(string text)
    {
        return new string(text.Reverse().ToArray());
    }
}
```

For the command line described in this question, you'd call it like this:

```
string commandLine = WindowsCommandLineHelper.FormatCommandLine(
    "-i", finPath, "-ar", "44100", "-ab", "160k", foutPath);
Process.Start(exePath, commandLine);
```

**UPDATE**

There is more interesting information along these lines in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/), and a [C# implementation here](https://github.com/natemcmaster/CommandLineUtils/blob/master/src/CommandLineUtils/Utilities/ArgumentEscaper.cs).

Answer (score 2):

Is this just a problem escaping the quotes? The code you posted uses "" instead of \". For C# it should be:

```
string cmd = " -i \"" + finPath + "\" -ar 44100 -ab 160k \"" + foutPath + "\"";
```

Comment: No, the problem is adding quotes around finPath and foutPath.

Comment: @Haste: this will add quotes around those two variables. Your code was using "" instead of \", which is what you need in C#.

Answer (score 0):

And here's my attempt:

```
    public static string QuoteArgument(string arg)
    {
        // The inverse of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx

        // Suppose we wish to get after unquoting: \\share\"some folder"\
        // We should provide: "\\share\\\"some folder\"\\"

        // Escape quotes ==> \\share\\\"some folder\"\
        // For quotes with N preceding backslashes, replace with 2k+1 preceding backslashes.
        var res = new StringBuilder();
        // For sequences of backslashes before quotes:
        // odd ==> 2x+1, even => 2x ==> "\\share\\\"some folder"
        var numBackslashes = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < arg.Length; ++i)
        {
            if(arg[i] == '"')
            {
                res.Append('\\', 2 * numBackslashes + 1);
                res.Append('"');
                numBackslashes = 0;
            }
            else if(arg[i] == '\\')
            {
                numBackslashes++;
            }
            else
            {
                res.Append('\\', numBackslashes);
                res.Append(arg[i]);
                numBackslashes = 0;
            }
        }
        res.Append('\\', numBackslashes);

        // Enquote, doubling last sequence of backslashes ==> "\\share\\\"some folder\"\\"
        var numTrailingBackslashes = 0;
        for (var i = res.Length - 1; i > 0; --i)
        {
            if (res[i] != '\\')
            {
                numTrailingBackslashes = res.Length - 1 - i;
                break;
            }
        }
        res.Append('\\', numTrailingBackslashes);

        return '"' + res.ToString() + '"';
    }
```