# Process.Start with network share AND spaces

Tags: c#, file, process, network-share

I am trying to start word from a C# app passing as argument a file that is on a network share with spaces. I have searched and can only find working examples with files with spaces only on local storage, not on network shares.

I have had only success mapping the network share to a letter, such as:

```
Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE", "\"k:\\coordinacion de apoyo a usuarios\\informes\\2015\\2015-10\\informe octubre 2015.docx\"");
```

But the following does NOT work:

```
Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE", "\"\\mar-fp01\\mar_tecnologia$\\coordinacion de apoyo a usuarios\\informes\\2015\\2015-10\\informe octubre 2015.docx\"");
```

(K: is mapped to \mar-fp01\mar_tecnologia$)

Also, i don't want to hard code the location, since in reality i get the file name from:

```
SaveFileDialog archivo = new SaveFileDialog();
archivo.FileName = "informe "+ months.GetValue(month - 1) + " " + year;
archivo.InitialDirectory = @"\\mar-fp01\mar_tecnologia$\Coordinacion de Apoyo a Usuarios\Informes\" + year + "\\" + year + "-" + monthYear[0].PadLeft(2, '0');
```

So a proper solution should take archivo.FileName and do a minimal conversion to its value to ensure Process.Start would work. I have tried using the @ delimiter, also ProcessStartInfo with its Arguments property and no combination i have tried works. This question should help anyone that has to mess with files with spaces on network shares.

Comment: There should be a double back-slash before the server name, when working with UNC paths. Does `"\"\\\\mar-fp01\\...` work any better?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952721/problems-launching-a-process-with-process-start-how-do-i-construct-the-argum/952852#952852

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes it worked and that helped me into finding the solution, i just had to add the quotes before and after archivo.fileName. See the edited question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE", "\""+archivo.FileName+"\"");
```

Where archivo is an instance of SaveFileDialog as follows:

```
SaveFileDialog archivo = new SaveFileDialog();
archivo.Filter = "Archivos .docx (*.docx)|*.docx|Todos los archivos (*.*)|*.*";
archivo.FileName = "filename with spaces";
archivo.InitialDirectory = @"\\server\share$\folder with spaces\another folder";
```

The InitialDirectory property should be preceded with @ to ensure the proper escaping is done.